# Compact encoding of sudoku puzzles

Tags: discussion

I just "renewed" my password after a two-year absence (Jan. 2013).

I answered the question re "minimum number of bits require to store a Sudoku puzzle" by describing a program implementation.  I have an update that reduces the encoding time by half, and I wonder if I could describe this here.

Thanks,

user "JScott"

Answer (score 4):

You should just click the 'edit' button on [your answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16263/1037) and update that answer.

However, note that this is a site for *theoretical* computer science, and users here are seldom interested in (the details of) implementations. Your efforts might be more appreciated on the [CodeGolf version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41523/sudoku-compression) of this question.